# VBA "linking" lists to get specific data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm asking my question here because I am a bit lost and don't have the right key-words to find an answer on the net for my problem.

I have two excel worksheets. One is a data base, the other is interacting with it. In the database, I have multiple headers parameters : Name, Code and three others parameterss that we'll call Data to sum it up. 
In the interacting worksheet, I want a selection window with a drop-down list for the Name, in which I'll select a name, and a selection window with a drop-down list for the Code, in which I'll select a Code which is relative to a Name. (There are several Name instances which are the same, but are different because of their unique code.) Once the name and the right code have been selected, my Data is loaded in a result window which will regroup the Name, the Code and the corresponding Data.

So far, I have managed to make the list with the names included in it, through this method :

```
Sub NameList()
    Range("A13").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=DB!$A$2:$A$800"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Problem here is that it doesn't give me unique values, and since I have multiple names similar, the drop-down list is long and confusing. As for the code, I have to find it myself, then type it. Once I click on the "loading data" button, I get everything in my result window as I desire.

To sum it up, my needs are to :
- Get unique values in the drop-down ist for Names
- Get Code values which are corresponding to the Name value selected just before.

Thanks in advance for any form of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like so, to get the unique values.  The second argument in `dic.add` you could add an array of the corresponding row numbers.  Then your first list will be `join` of the `keys` and the 2nd will be the `join` of the cells at row numbers contained in `items` collection.

See this article https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

```
Sub DynamicCombo()

Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim l As Long
Dim c As Excel.Range

    For Each c In Range("AB1:AB10").Cells
        If Not dic.Exists(CStr(c)) Then
            dic.Add CStr(c), c.value '  Use an array here to hold row #'s
        End If
    Next c

    With Range("AC1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(dic.Keys(), ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

I have tried adapting this solution to my probem and I came across the error "User-defined type not defned." As a new player in the VBA game, I don't know how to react to this.

Comment: You need to add the reference to it, look at the early binding section in the link sent

Comment: Alright so I figured it out for the reference thing, however I have the problem in the code as the data is contained in another worksheets called database, and with your solution I don't know how to call it from that other worksheets

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  `Worksheets("Database").Range("AB1:AB10").Cells` is the way